# Xamarin Android Lottie Splash Screen

Tags: android, xamarin, lottie

https://www.project-respite.com/lottie-xamarin-forms/

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.  I followed the steps on the tutorial, but I am getting this error "View does not contain the definition of 'AddAnimationListner'..."

I've tried using these [1]classes as well: addAnimatorUpdateListener and addAnimationListner.

What can I do to fix it?

Code:
screenshot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJZ1o.jpg

```
using Android.Animation;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Lottie.Forms.Droid;
using Com.Airbnb.Lottie;


namespace RefrigerantID.Droid
{
    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
        MainLauncher = true,
        NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity : Activity, Animator.IAnimatorListener
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.splash);

            var animationView = FindViewById(Resource.Id.animation_view);
            animationView.AddAnimationListener(this);
        }

        public void OnAnimationCancel(Animator animation)
        {
        }

        public void OnAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
        {
            StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)));
        }

        public void OnAnimationRepeat(Animator animation)
        {
        }

        public void OnAnimationStart(Animator animation)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I am trying todo the same do you happen to have a working sample I cannot make it work I am following the same link.greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about...

```
var animationView = FindViewById<LottieAnimationView>(Resource.Id.animation_view);
animationView.AddAnimationListener(this);
```

Comment: Hey, I'm now receiving this error, do you know what could cause this?

https://imgur.com/a/x5pYqdz

Comment: Check if the id "animation_view" was applied to the correct element in your Activity_Splash.axml